# What tense should I use in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, past-tense, present-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

1. During the holidays, students should revise the topics that they have learned in grade 2.  or
2. During the holidays, students should revise the topics that they learned in grade 2.

For me it looks more natural to say that they have learned in grade 2 but grade 2 is over now and therefore I think the past tense tense is more appropriate.
Are they both correct?  If so, what is the difference in their meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine, they both have the same meaning.

For the sake of brevity though, I feel "During the holidays, students should revise the topics that they learned in grade 2" is more idiomatic.

Comment: E.Aigle  thanks!

Comment: I agree; either one is correct.  The simple past "that they learned" is probably preferable simply because there isn't any specific reason to use the present perfect.  The learning that they did last year is completely over and done, so the simple past is appropriate.